# Execution algorithm recursively seeking lower number, is very slow

Tags: c, algorithm, recursion

Hi I have the following code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

#define min(x, y)(x < y)?(x):(y)
#define SIZE 1000

int valormenor(int a[], int n)
{
    if(n == 1)
        return a[0];
    else
        return min(a[0], valormenor(a + 1, n - 1));
}

int main(void)
{
    int arr[SIZE] = {0}, i;
    srand (time (NULL));
    for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        arr[i] = rand() % SIZE;
    arr[5] = -1;
    printf("%d\n", valormenor(arr, SIZE));

    return 0;
}
```

The point is that do not understand because it takes too long to find the smallest number, my theory is that this recursive function is badly implemented, you who claim to?

Comment: How slow is "very slow"? But of course you're right in that this is a ridiculously slow way to find the minimum value in an array _compared to a simple loop_, due to all the unnecessary overhead.

Comment: @romkyns can you explain why this function is inefficient

Comment: Your algorithm is O(n)²

Comment: @xsami more like O(2^n)

Comment: even without the `min` double evaluation, `valormenor` recurses `n` times, you are going to run out of stack space for moderately large values of `n`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Let's expand the `min` macro here:

```
return min(a[0], valormenor(a + 1, n - 1));
```

That becomes

```
return (a[0] < valormenor(a + 1, n - 1))?(a[0]):(valormenor(a + 1, n - 1));
```

As you can see, `valormenor` is called twice. Those two recursive calls make four recursive calls, which make eight recursive calls, and so on. It's a classic double evaluation bug.

Don't use macros like this. They're just not worth the headaches.

Comment: @Tony: Don't do that. One question per question.

Comment: Furthermore: the macro is not properly parenthesized!  it should be `#define MIN(x, y)((x) < (y))?(x):(y)`.  To avoid the multiple evaluation, make it a function.  For performance, this function can be made `static` or better `static inline`.